# SPList is a 'namespace' but is used like a 'type'

Tags: c#, sharepoint, outlook, version

I am having problems in the import of SpList. I tried to copy paste a lot of the sharepoint imports but still is not fixed. Please help me fix this one error. Thank you.

```
    public void CheckVersionEnable(string ListName)
    {
        SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
        {
            using (SPSite osite = new SPSite("http://it3127:30091/"))
            {
                using (SPWeb oweb = osite.OpenWeb("http://it3127:30091/"))
                {

                    SPList docs = oweb.Lists[ListName];
                    if (docs.EnableVersioning == false)
                    {
                        docs.EnableVersioning = true;
                        docs.MajorVersionLimit = 10;
                        oweb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                        docs.Update();
                        oweb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you haven't included:

```
using Microsoft.SharePoint;
```

At the top of the file (Or inside your namespace) you will have to prefix it as:

```
Microsoft.SharePoint.SPList list;
```

As an additional note, ensure you don't have:

```
   namespace SPList {

   }
```

In your solution.  It sounds like there's a namespace with the `SPList` name and you're attempting to create a new type from it (Rather than the actual `SPList` class)

Comment: I have include this imports but still wont let it work;


using Microsoft.SharePoint;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.SPList;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurableObject;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.SPDocumentLibrary;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.SPIssueList;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities;

Comment: @kyrul - can you try changing `SPList docs` to `Microsoft.SharePoint.SPList docs`